# Выход блока за рамки дозволенного

Tags: html, css

Ребята, у меня вопрос, почему контент не уменьшается по высоте, а просто статично остаётся размер и поэтому появляется белый отступ снизу страницы. Вот картинка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код элементов:

```
.bg {
  background-color: rgba(15, 26, 47, 0.9);
  max-width: 920px;
  max-height: 420px;
  z-index: 36;
  position: relative;
}// синий блок

.goodsright,
.goodsleft {
font-size: 16px;
letter-spacing: 0.02em;
line-height: 1.25;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 40px;
z-index:36;
}// контент внутри синего блока

.signform {
  background-color: rgb( 255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 140px 0px rgb( 50, 66, 91);
  max-width: 462px;
  height: 462px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 435px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  transition: all ease 0.7s;    
  z-index:50;
} // белый блок
```

Comment: соберите [mcve], что это за css, и откуда, как расположены дивы, что еще на них влияет, гадать невозможно

Answer (score 1):

Присвой белому блоку высоту родителя

```
.signform {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 140px 0px rgb(50, 66, 91);
    max-width: 462px;
    height: inherit; // Присваиваем высоту родителя; а можно вообще убрать эту строку
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 435px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    transition: all ease 0.7s;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Если нужно, чтобы снизу не было отступа, измени `bottom: 20px;` на `bottom: 0px;`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мы не про одни и те же отступы говорим, внимательно взгляни на backgorund-image(100vh) и посмотри, как блок выходит за него, хотя не должен

Comment: дело в том, что блок bg не меняет свой размер по высоте, он уменьшается по ширине, но по высоте не хочет

Comment: @FeelsBadMan, так как он будет меняться по высоте, если она у тебя фиксированная?

Comment: давно max-height: 420px   это фиксированная высота?

Comment: @FeelsBadMan, добавь `height: 100%;`

Comment: Всё, разобрался, оказывается bgr-image был в блоке .content , а надо было поместить в боди, теперь всё красиво